# PHP - Extracting all files of rar archive to main folder

Tags: php, archive, rar

I have a rar file with the many files and folders. I want to extract files in the sub-folders of the rar file to the main folder.

I have tried this:

```
$archive = RarArchive::open('example.rar');

$entries = $archive->getEntries();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
    $entry->extract($dir);

$archive->close();
```

However this extracts the files to the same folder, rather than the main folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `$entry->extract(null, $dir.'/'.basename($entry->getName()));`? http://php.net/manual/en/rarentry.extract.php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions no, it's extracted in same folder again.

Comment: Dont know what is in `$dir` (Path (relative or absolute) ) :-)  But you helped yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried an own solution, and it's works:

```
$archive = RarArchive::open('example.rar');

$entries = $archive->getEntries();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($entry->getName());
        copy("rar://".$file."#".$entry->getName(), $dir.'/'.$fileinfo['basename']);
}

$archive->close();
```

for don't extract folders (empty folders), we can put

```
if(!empty($fileinfo['extension']))
```

before **copy** function.

thanks to me :-)